# Stack in Constructor

Tags: java

```
Card karte;
Stack <Card> kartenstapel;

 public Standard52() {

     /** this works*/
     this.karte = new Card(Suit.HEARTS,13);                       

     /** this throws a 0-pointer exception when I try to initial*/

     this.kartenstapel.addElement(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, 13));
     this.kartenstapel.addElement(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, 13));
     this.kartenstapel.addElement(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, 13));
     this.kartenstapel.addElement(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, 13));
 }
```

Why i get a null pointer exception when i try to inital it. 
Its more theorie then practice but i do not undersstand my failure maybe some of you can explain me where my mistake is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You have not initialized `kartenstapel` which is why it is throwing an exception. Initialize it by `Stack <Card> kartenstapel = new Stack<>();` and then proceed to run the code. It should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the `Stack` as well. So, it would be

```
public Standard52() {
    this.kartenstapel = new Stack<>();
    // now add elements
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the `Stack` collection:

```
Card karte;
Stack <Card> kartenstapel = new Stack<>(); // initialization to an empty stack

public Standard52() {

     /** this works*/
     this.karte = new Card(Suit.HEARTS,13);                       

     /** this should work as the kartenstapel is initialized */

     this.kartenstapel.addElement(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, 13));
     this.kartenstapel.addElement(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, 13));
     this.kartenstapel.addElement(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, 13));
     this.kartenstapel.addElement(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, 13));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `kartenstapel`.

```
Stack <Card> kartenstapel = new Stack<>();
```